# Custom keyboard layout in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am currently working on a BrainFuck interpreter for the iPhone. Seeing as BrainFuck only has eight commands, I want to create a custom nine-button (eight commands + backspace) keypad that will be showed instead of the standard iPhone keyboard. Is there any easy way of doing this?

Thanks,
amit ron-

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there's no "officially authorized" way to do this. The thread [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6275-add-toolbar-top-keyboard.html) is a good discussion of a variety of ways it can be done.

Also, the iPhone SDK agreement specifically forbids interpreters. I don't know how strictly that rule is kept, so be aware that your app may get rejected.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no easy way to do this elegantly, i.e. there are definitely no custom keyboards supported, only the ones supplied by the system. (Shouldn't be too hard to implement your own for nine buttons though).

If you look carefully at some galleries of the new iPad, you can see that Numbers for iPad has a custom keyboard. I think this makes it quite likely that doing something like this will probably become easier once the next iPhone OS is out.