# Custom Numbers & Punctuation Keypad for UITextField

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextfield

Hey guys  , I am using a Numbers & Punctuation Keypad for the UITextfield ,
I want the user be able to use only the follows keys : 
1. Numbers
2. Decimal / Dot /Period
3. Done / Return Key

I want to disable all the characters as well as the Spacebar , how can I do that ? 
Well I could have used the Number Keypad but then how am I supposed get the Decimal / Dot / Period in it ..?? 
I am also trying to figure out was to Hide the Number keypad after the user clicks on a the
Remaining screen.

Regards ,
Omkar Jadhav

Comment: This question is very similar to these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171258/custom-keyboard-layout-in-cocoa-touch and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610542/custom-iphone-keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently can't modify the keyboards that the iPhone provides.

To get rid of the keyboard, look into the resignFirstResponder message.  That question has probably been answered in explicit detail on here elsewhere.